# Ahoy_email gem - bypass ahoy_message creation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ahoy

I'm using the [Ahoy_Email](https://github.com/ankane/ahoy_email) gem in my rails app. Is there a setting to bypass the creation of the ahoy_message for certain emails - for example: I do not want to create a new ahoy message instance for test emails - I would like to bypass all functionality of this gem for those emails.

I added the following settings for my test emails: `track message: false`, `track click: false`, `track open: false`, `track utm_params: false` and they work, but the ahoy message instance is still created. I would imagine this is a very simple setting, but I just don't see how to do this in the documentation. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This can be a way to do it:

```rb
ahoy.track_message if message.subject.include?('Test')
```